# Is it mandatory to check for Multicollinearity and Normality in the independent variables for all types of Machine Learning Algorithms?

Tags: multicollinearity, normality-assumption

Is it mandatory to check for Multicollinearity and Normality in the independent variables for all types of Machine Learning Algorithms ?

Comment: What do you think you need normality of IVs on? It's not an assumption for ordinary mutliple regression, for example

Comment: I have seen a few Data Scientists Advocating the need to check Normality and also Multicollinearity. But in my experience so far, I have seldom encountered datasets in which the independent variables are normally distributed. What should I do in such a case ? Should I leave the dataset as it is or should I try to apply some type of a transformation to make the variables Normal ? Also on multicollinearity, should I be worried about it ? If so, in what types of Machine Learning Algorithms it might cause problems.

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian I think preprocessing has an important role to play. and it should be applied wherever possible. Because subsequent analytical actions depend heavily on the same. So whether its classification or clustering, I think preprocessing is a "necessary evil".

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. It would be helpful if we can delve into some specific details here. What issues do you have practically encountered due to Non-Normality and/or Multicollinearity ? Also, in case you encounter non-normality in your independent variables, how do you take care of the same?

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian Your question is too broad. Narrow down to a specific model.

Comment: Multicollinearity is not necessarily a bad thing. We have algorithms for extracting latent components from them.

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian Multicollinearity (also collinearity) is a phenomenon in which two or more variables are highly correlated such that one variable can be linearly predicted from the other. If not addressed it definitely reduces the reliability of individual variable’s contribution to the regression model. See [Variance Inflation Factor](http://www.statisticshowto.com/variance-inflation-factor/) which helps in detecting it.

Answer (score 2):

No statistical or ML method requires IVs to be normally distributed.

(What is often important is that certain *test statistics*, like the sample mean, be asymptotically normally distributed. A sufficient but not necessary condition for this is that residuals be normal. This is often confused.)

If a "data scientist" believes that IVs should be normally distributed, I would recommend you probe more deeply. Either he has a reason in a particular application that I have never come across, or he is propagating a misunderstanding.

[multicollinearity](/questions/tagged/multicollinearity) [increases the variance of a parameter estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). In extreme cases, the estimate can be totally meaningless. It is often good practice to check for multicollinearity. It is even better to first understand your data and think about which IVs might be multicollinear.

Answer (score -2):

No. I never did that on decision trees.

Comment: What for other types of Machine Learning Techniques, like Linear / Logistic Regression ? Do you check for Normality and Multicollinearity for them ?

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian No regression requires normality as far I know.

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian I do check for multicollinearity for regression but certainly not "all" machine learning algorithms. As said, I don't think I would have it do it on DT.

Comment: Thanks @SmallChess. Can you also elude into what issues you expect due to multicollinearity in a regression ? I believe that you do not see the same issue with DT and therefore you do not perform this check there.

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian Multicollinearity in regression is well documented on this site. Hundreds of questions about it. Glen_b may give you some help.

Comment: Thanks @SmallChess. I have found a lot of write-ups on how to treat multicollinearity. But I have had mixed reactions on whether it is a problem at the first place. How does it affect outcome of a Linear Regression, whereas it doesnt affect DT ?

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian Your question is too complicated for me to answer in a comment. I'd suggest you accept my answer (which is correct), and then ask a new question. Otherwise, please edit your question.

Comment: @NithyaSubramanian you'll be better of by narrowing down the focus of your question. I recommend to edit it.